# Bootstrap 3: Don't use some classes when resolution is small

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am playing with the new bootstrap, i use a pull-right on my menu, but when im on mobile + tablet ress i dont want it to use the pull-right, is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use media queries for this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries. Use media queries to reset or overwrite the default style.
In the case of `.pull-right` you use this to reset the floating right:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) { .pull-right{float:none !important;} }
```

Of course you could vary the `max-width` to fit your need. B.e. use 991px for phone and tablets.